# tkinter centering two or more widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I created a frame in which I want to put two widgets with them being centered on the x-axis. When it's one object pack() centers it automatically. But I can't figure out two widgets. I tried with grid() but there is free space left on the right which makes it look unsymetrical as seen in the image.
[image]

how could I get what is seen on the right? (I'd prefer it being dont with pack() but if there is a solution with grid() and/or place() as well i'd appreciate those as well!)

here's the code for the left picture

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

frame = Frame(root, bg="white", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
frame.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.5, relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

label = Label(frame, bg="lime", text="label", font=font.Font(size=20))
label.grid(column=0, row=0)

button = Button(frame, bg="yellow", text="pressbutton", font=font.Font(size=20))
button.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `frame.pack()` to easily position the frame in the top, middle of its parent.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

frame = Frame(root, bg="white", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
frame.pack()

label = Label(frame, bg="lime", text="label", font=font.Font(size=20))
label.grid(column=0, row=0)

button = Button(frame, bg="yellow", text="pressbutton", font=font.Font(size=20))
button.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: that seems like the most obvious soloution but in my project I already use a lot of frames inside frames. Is this not kind of messy? Or is this the only/best way?

Comment: No, an architecture that requires widgets inside frames, inside frames is perfectly normal for a GUI of any serious scope. The choice between `grid` and `pack` is dictated by the design constraints, but you have not shared those.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the label and button in another frame, and use `pack()` on that frame:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

frame = Frame(root, bg="white", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
frame.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.5, relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

frame2 = Frame(frame)
frame2.pack() # default side='top'

label = Label(frame2, bg="lime", text="label", font=font.Font(size=20))
label.pack(side='left', fill='both')

button = Button(frame2, bg="yellow", text="pressbutton", font=font.Font(size=20))
button.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```